# Unable to run python.exe containing playwright

Tags: python, pyinstaller, playwright

I created a script and turn it into an .exe file using pyinstaller but was unable to run the .exe without encountering the following error:

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 31, in <module>
  File "playwright\sync_api\_generated.py", line 11436, in launch
  File "playwright\_impl\_sync_base.py", line 111, in _sync
  File "playwright\_impl\_browser_type.py", line 90, in launch
  File "playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 39, in send
  File "playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 63, in inner_send
playwright._impl._api_types.Error: Executable doesn't exist at C:\(...)\chrome.exe*

╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Looks like Playwright Test or Playwright was just installed or updated. ║
║ Please run the following command to download new browsers:              ║
║                                                                         ║
║     playwright install                                                  ║
║                                                                         ║
║ <3 Playwright Team                                                      ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
[9084] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

I have already installed playwright on my computer.

[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install browsers by doing `playwright install` or `python -m playwright install` see here: https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro#installation

Comment: I've already ran the command on my computer. 

But the script only works when I ran it for my IDE but gives this issue on my .exe

Is there a way I can trigger this command when someone double clicks on my .exe file?

Comment: For pyinstaller see here https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro#pyinstaller

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to install the browser that will be used by playwright first. To do this, type in bash:

```
PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=0 playwright install chromium
pyinstaller -F main.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This guide explains how to create an .exe file using Playwright https://medium.com/@animeshsingh161/how-to-convert-a-python-playwright-script-into-an-executable-app-playwright-with-python-b61d8ff0ca64 using an venv; however, as a Windows user is important to add the keyword set on the terminal on step 3 (set PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=0 playwright install browser), where browser is the browser that you are using, for example, set PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=0 playwright install firefox. The browser is optional, but, if you type it, it is going to save you space.